# My project doesn't work for simulator iPhone 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode4.5

Symptom

1. It works if I try to run it with iPhone 5.1
2. If I run with simulator 6.1 the project start and then "finish". That's it. No error message. Nothing.
3. I put breakpoint at - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions it's never called
4. Clean the project doesn't solve the issue

I don't know what else I can do.

Because of this I cannot take screen shot of 4 inch. It seems that the 4 inch retina screenshot can only be done with simulator 6.1

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: no. not at all. One project works. This one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

When you run application .
 Don't for get to select Deployment Target 6.

[image]

Comment: I got 2 warnings but same symptom (no error). The 2 warnings are /business/Dropbox/badgers/RecentContact/RCABAddressBookHandler.m:51:19: 'ABAddressBookCreate' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 6.0. The code doesn't even reach that point.